# Getting Facebook event venue latitude & longitude

Tags: php, facebook

Hello I use the following code in order to retrieve an events infoormation from facebook based on the url provided.

The code is this:

```
function importEvent($url) 
{
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => 'someAppId',
          'secret' => 'someSecret',
          'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
        )); 

    if(checkLogin()==true)
    {   
        //get rid of hash if exists
        $hash = explode('#',$url);

        if(!empty($hash[1]))
            $array = parse_url($hash[1]);
        else
            $array = parse_url($hash[0]);

        parse_str($array['query'],$output);
        $eid = $output['eid'];

        if(empty($eid))//new url think http://www.facebook.com/events/2323423423423/
        {
            $url = str_replace('http://www.facebook.com/events/','',$url);
            $url = str_replace('https://www.facebook.com/events/','',$url);
            $hash = explode('/?',$url);

            if(!empty($hash[1]))
                $url = $hash[0];

            $eid =   str_replace('?','',$url);  
            $eid =   str_replace('/','',$url);
            //print_r($eid);
        }
            //Calling users.getinfo legacy api call example
            try{
                $param  =   array(
                    'method'  => 'events.get',
                    'eids'    => $eid,
                    'access_token' => $_SESSION['access_token']

                );
                $events   =   $facebook->api($param);
            }
            catch(Exception $o){
                error_log($o);
                echo $o; 
            }

        print_r($events);   
        return $events;
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [eid] => 410474065693887
            [name] => Sunday Night Fever Vol.4  Disco Special @Legacy Rock Area
            [pic_small] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/276862_410474065693887_714884848_t.jpg
            [pic_big] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/276862_410474065693887_714884848_n.jpg
            [pic] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/276862_410474065693887_714884848_s.jpg
            [pic_square] => http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/276862_410474065693887_714884848_q.jpg
            [has_profile_pic] => 1
            [host] => Legacy Rock Area
            [version] => 2
            [description] => Αφου μας το ζητησατε "παρτε" το..!!!

Μετα το τελευταιο απιστευτο killer Disco Party εχουμε την ευκαιρια να κανουμε προθερμανση για τον Super Αποκριατικο Φεβρουαριο που θα ακολουθησει στο Legacy Rock Area μεμια βραδυα γεματη Disco,Dance,Pop και οπου μας βγαλει...!!

Κυριακη 20 Ιανουαριου λοιπον..Sunday Night Fever Disco Special!!!

That night the DJ saves our lives...!!!
            [start_time] => 2013-01-20
            [end_time] => 
            [timezone] => 
            [is_date_only] => 1
            [creator] => 1732432279
            [update_time] => 1357737066
            [location] => Legacy Rock Area
            [hide_guest_list] => 
            [can_invite_friends] => 
            [privacy] => OPEN
            [venue] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 244479685665743
                )

            [all_members_count] => 7175
            [attending_count] => 74
            [unsure_count] => 144
            [declined_count] => 509
            [not_replied_count] => 6957
        )

)
```

However on the api documentation it mentions that venue contains the following:

The location of this event
generic access_token, user_events or friends_events
object containing one or more of the following fields: id, street, city, state, zip, country, latitude, and longitude fields.

But all I'm getting is the venue id.

I couldn't locate a specific piece of information on how to retrieve lat + lng of a venue place and I assume that this code is ok if I'm not mistaken.

Do I need to execute another query just for the venue info and if so could you please provide any reference or code examples? Or is there a way for this piece of code to return the lat + lng also, so I wont have to do 2 queries for 1 event?

Comment: How about removing the legacy api and just use: `$events   =   $facebook->api($eid);`?

Comment: Ok I did that how could I get information and other properties of the event? because the otuput is limited as i can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've found that that this could be doen with fql.multiquery and it seems to work fine now. Here is the source code.

```
function importEventFQL($url)
{
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => 'someApddID',
          'secret' => 'someSecret',
          'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
        )); 

    if(checkLogin()==true)
    {   

        list($url_static,$url_URI) = explode('/events',$url);

        $url_URI = ltrim($url_URI,'/');
        list($eid, $trash) = explode('/?',$url_URI);

        $fql = '{';

        $fql .= '"event_info":"SELECT name, description, pic_small, pic_big, eid, venue, location, start_time, end_time, host from event WHERE eid=\'' . $eid . '\'",';
        $fql .= '"event_venue":"SELECT name, username, page_id, location FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT venue.id FROM #event_info)"';

        $fql .= '}';

        $param = array(
            'method'   => 'fql.multiquery',
            'queries'  => $fql,
            'callback' => ''
        );

        $result = $facebook->api($param);

        print_r($result);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the FQL to do this:

```
{
    "events" : "SELECT privacy, name, description, start_time, venue.id, pic_cover FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())",
    "venues" : "SELECT latitude, longitude, name, page_id FROM place WHERE page_id IN (SELECT  venue.id FROM #events)"
}
```